# Linear algebra: Solving a system of equation matrix with a variable as coefficient.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's consider this augmented matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    3 &-6 &6 &15\\
    -2 &7 &a &-25\\
    2 &-6 &6 & 20
\end{array}\right)$$

I'm trying to figure how to solve a matrix like this when there is $a$ as one of the coefficients.

Comment: In exactly the same way as you would if $a$ was some specific number with the following caveat: you may **not** divide by $a$.  The reason being, if $a$ were zero, you would run into problems with division by zero errors.  You will end up with a set of possible $a$ for which you have a unique solution.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'solving a matrix'? You can solve a system of equations or find a determinant of a matrix.

Comment: @NoChance the notation seems to imply that this is an augmented matrix and that he is searching for the vector $x$ that solves the equation $Ax=b$, or in more symbols, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3&-6&6\\-2&7&a\\ 2&-6&6\end{smallmatrix}\right] \left[\begin{smallmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{smallmatrix}\right] = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 15\\-25\\20\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Comment: @JMoravitz, Clear, thanks.

Comment: From the first and third rows of the matrix,
$$ 3x_1 - 6x_2 + 6x_3 = 15 \quad \text{ and } \quad 2x_1 - 6x_1 + 6x_3 = 20$$
Now you can subtract the latter equation from the former to find $x_1 = -5$. Proceeding like this you should be able to find an expression relating $a$ and your unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

Procede with the usual row reduction, trying to avoid pivoting on the element with $a$ as long as possible:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    3 &-6 &6 &15\\
    -2 &7 &a &-25\\
    2 &-6 &6 & 20
\end{array}\right)
\xrightarrow{\begin{matrix}R1~/~3\\R3~/~2\end{matrix}}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    1 &-2 &2 &5\\
    -2 &7 &a &-25\\
    1 &-3 &3 & 10
\end{array}\right)
\xrightarrow{\begin{matrix}R2~+~2R1\\R3~-~R1\end{matrix}}\\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    1 &-2 &2 &5\\
    0 &3 &a+4 &-15\\
    0 &-1 &1 & 5
\end{array}\right)
\xrightarrow{\begin{matrix}R_3~\times~-1\\R3~\leftrightarrow~R2\end{matrix}}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    1 &-2 &2 &5\\
    0 &1 &-1 & -5\\
    0 &3 &a+4 &-15
\end{array}\right)
\xrightarrow{\begin{matrix}R_3~-~3R2\end{matrix}}\\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    1 &-2 &2 &5\\
    0 &1 &-1 & -5\\
    0 &0 &a+7 &0
\end{array}\right)
$$

What happens next depends on whether $a+7=0$:

- Case $a=-7$: then the bottom row is $0~0~0~|~0$, the set of equations is consistent and has an infinite number of solutions.
- Case $a\ne-7$: then we can divide $R3$ by $a+7$ to get $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1 &-2 &2 &5\\
      0 &1 &-1 & -5\\
      0 &0 &1 &\dfrac{1}{a+7}
  \end{array}\right)
  $$ and the set of equations has a unique solution.